# Open the same .txt file to write in it in two different php

Tags: php, file

In my first php file I open the users.txt to read it and then write in it. Here is the code for it:
Read:

```
if(file_exists("users.txt")){
    $handle = fopen("users.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        ...
    } else {
        $ERROR = "Can't open the 'users.txt' file";
    }
    if ($userExist === true) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
} else {
        ...
}
```

write:

```
$file = fopen("users.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open the file");
$data = PHP_EOL. $UserId . " " . $Fname . " " . $Lname . " " . $pass;
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

In my second php file, I tried to open the same file but apprently when I do this code:

```
$file = fopen("users.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open the file");
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $data = " " . $Phone . " " . $recoveryEmail . " " . $month . " " . $day . " " . $year . " " . $gender;
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
}
else{
    echo "Can't open the file 'users.txt'";
}
```

When I run it everything works fine for my first php file, but for second it prints the message:

Can't open the file 'users.txt'

Answer (score 0):

After you use the fopen function, the $file is a handle, not the file name.

Hence please amend as follows:

```
$file = fopen("users.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open the file");
if (file_exists("users.txt")) {
    $data = " " . $Phone . " " . $recoveryEmail . " " . $month . " " . $day . " " . $year . " " . $gender;
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
}
else{
    echo "Can't open the file 'users.txt'";
}
```